# Can I do something while the app is being installed?

Tags: java, android

There are some actions that I wanted to be done while the app is being  installed(Like onCreate but the method should be called only the time that the app is being installed on the device). The reason for that is because this action may need too much time to be done and I don't want user to wait.
Thanks in advance.
Ps:I don't  wana use doInBackground

Comment: android studio is an IDE, it just helps you to code. unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE specifically, please don't use the android-studio tag

Answer (score 3):

> Can I do something while the app is being installed?

No, sorry.

First, literally while your app is being installed, your app is not installed yet, and therefore cannot run.

If you really mean "right after the app is installed", the answer is still no. That used to be a possibility, many years ago, and it was exploited by "drive-by" malware, so it has been blocked since Android 3.1.

Comment: Thanks a million. What's your suggested way?Should I go for doInBackground?Or  there is something else related ?

Comment: @Ali_Rahgozar: "What's your suggested way?" -- do something when your app is first run. We do not know what you are trying to do, other than it is slow. "Should I go for doInBackground?" -- if you mean `AsyncTask`, no. That class is deprecated. `WorkManager` may be a candidate.